# Clickable HeroCard images

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I can't seem to find any documentation or forum answers to making an image in a HeroCard clickable. I want to be able to click the image and perform the same `imBack()` action as I would with a button.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the Hero card's image to go that link by using the `Tap` property of the `HeroCard`.

Posting some sample code in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Bot_Application2.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(ConversationStartedAsync);
        }

        public async Task ConversationStartedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            IMessageActivity reply = context.MakeMessage();

            HeroCard heroCard = new HeroCard()
            {
                Title = "I'm a hero card",
                Images = new List<CardImage>
                {
                new CardImage(url: $"https://www.google.org/assets/static/images/logo_googledotorg-171e7482e5523603fc0eed236dd772d8.svg")
                },
                Tap = new CardAction()
                {
                    Value = $"https://www.google.co.in/",
                    Type = "openUrl",
                }
            };

            reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>
                {
                    heroCard.ToAttachment()
                };

            await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with a `HeroCard`. You might want to explore [AdaptiveCards](http://adaptivecards.io/) which allows that.

Comment: That's unfortunate. But AdaptiveCards can't do an `imBack()` action right?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Getting a message posted in the chat after you click the image?

Comment: That would be ideal. But if it's not possible, performing any action after clicking the image would work.

Comment: Then probably using Action.Submit will suit your needs (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/create/gettingstarted#actions)